Read data from subcategories on Realtime Database (Firebase)
I am trying to read the message inputs from ALL users. I can do it for a specific user but I would like to do it for all of them by specifying in my code, however, each UID is unique...
My Realtime Database is setup as:
-Realtime Database Tree-

--- chats ---
             |
            UID (unique) ---
                            |
                            email: example@mail.com
                            message: Hello World.
                            date: Tues Apr 16 2024


I tried the current code below:
const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
            get(child(dbRef, 'chats/')).then((snapshot) => {
              if (snapshot.exists()) {

                const snaps = snapshot.val();
                console.log(snaps);


              } else {
                console.log("No data available");
              }
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);


            });

I want to retrieve the email, message, and date to display it into the console.log. I can do it with specific UID's like
            get(child(dbRef, 'chats/specific_UID')).then((snapshot) => {
              if (snapshot.exists()) {

                const snaps = snapshot.val().message;
                console.log(snaps);


However, I want to get the data inside each UID from the email, message, and date.
How can I do this?

Following the code example in the Firebase documentation on reading a list of nodes with a value events, that be:
const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
get(child(dbRef, 'chats/')).then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    const value = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(value);
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});


I looked at the link and tried that. Now I'm getting "Malformed arrow function parameter list". Never seen this error before.

snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot) => has one brace too much or too little. Either snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => or snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot =>

Good catch Moritz, I fixed the typo.
